# Modify Git commits in a branch without resolving conflicts

Tags: git

I have what I hope isn't an impossible problem to solve without having to do it by hand.

Recently, a project I'm working on decided to once and for all solve all of our whitespace baggage and clean it all up with one commit. We decided to use GNU indent to do this so we'd easily be able to agree on the format in the future. So the result is that I have a script which will format all of the code properly. The problem is that we also have various developers working on feature branches whose patches all have conflicts now.

What I want is a way to modify those patches without having to resolve the conflicts on each of them until I've run the script over all of them. When I amend each commit in turn by running the cleanup script, the next patch still has a massive number of conflicts because it expected all the whitespace to be different than it currently is.

Is there a way to modify these commits with this script and ignore any formatting changes when doing so (probably not because we're breaking up lines of code with the formatting script)? Or modify the patches themselves with the script?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - Another option added after the original answer

---

You can configure `merge`'s default strategy to disregard whitespace-only changes.  If you do, it will *disregard* them - potentially undoing them in the merge if they're in conflict.  But if you're applying the cleanup script to all branches, maybe that works out alright (because git might disregard that you added some spaces here, but it's doing so in favor of you changing the code *and adding those same spaces* on the other branch).

```
git merge -X ignore-space-change feature
```

(There are actually several different options you can use depending on what whitespace you want to ignore; see the `git merge` docs under "Merge Strategies", in the section on "Recursive".)

In cases where you split lines, this may not avoid the conflict; but if it removes 90% of the manual work, that's better than nothing.

I'll include my usual caveat, that giving options that change the merge result can potentially be a bad thing, especially if the default merge options would've produced a non-conflicting result.  But in your use case, the default options would generate a conflict; and the change in behavior "makes sense" if you're just de-conflicting clean-up that was done on both branches; so it's probably not so bad here.

---

Now, I may not be correctly following your comment about rebasing the branches, because it's not clear to me why "they are unmerged feature branches" would imply "so I have to rebase"...  But if you're saying that you plan to rebase (or in any sense rewrite) the feature branches anyway, then you have additional options.

For example, suppose you have

```
x -- x -- x -- C <--(master)
      \
       F -- G <--(feature)
```

where `C` is the clean-up commit on `master`; and your intent is to rebase `feature` to the `master` tip.  You could do something like

```
git rebase master^ feature
```

to incorporate non-cleanup changes, giving you

```
x -- x -- x -- C <--(master)
           \
            F' -- G' <--(feature)
```

Then do a "reparenting" operation to re-position the `feature` commits without changing their content (i.e. no merge operation).  You would use `git filter-branch`; the `--parent-filter` examples in the `filter-branch` docs give several ways to do this.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

```
x -- x -- x -- C <--(master)
                \
                 (F"-C) -- (G"-C) <--(feature)
```

Here I've denoted the new commits as `(F"-C)` to indicate that, whereas `F"` would be the result of a second rebase placing `F'` at `C`, in this case the `C` changes are implicitly "undone" because you reparent instead of rebasing.

Which is fine, because now at the `featuer` tip you re-run your clean-up script.  Since merging `feature` to `master` is now eligible to fast-forward (or equivalently, since the merge base would now be at `C`), there would be no conflicts.

```
x -- x -- x -- C <--(master)
                \
                 (F"-C) -- (G"-C) -- C2 <--(feature)
```

Now your history shows the clean-up work popping in and out of the code as you navigate the serialized branches; which to me is as clear an illustration as any that the linear history produced by rebase-based workflows is not unambiguously "cleaner" or "neater"; but that's mostly a separate issue.

Comment: This helps a little (though in my case, I need to rebase because these are all feature branches that aren't merged yet), but unfortunately a large part of what the cleanup script did was to split up lines and change whitespace within the line, which this filter doesn't seem to catch well. I should remove the whitespace tag as it's a bit of a red herring.